# Android Studio:Kotlin RegisterListener

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Android development and would like to learn how to get data from the Accelerometer.

I am following the example from this location: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager

When I build and run my application it quits with no warning or messages about errors. I looked through the event logs but did not see anything that looked like a problem, but I am new to android/Kotlin so I could be missing something.  When I run on my phone I get a message that the application has stopped on the emulator I get not messages.

The application fails sometime after the onResume event registers the listener and before the onSensorChanged event is called.  I added try catch, removed form the below code, statements around the code in each of the above mentioned functions and neither throw an exception.

The main class implements the SensorEventListener interface, all variables are initialized in the partial code below:

```
private lateinit var mSensorManager : SensorManager
private var mAccelerometer : Sensor ?= null
private var resume = false;

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    mSensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
    val deviceSensors: List<Sensor> = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL)
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
}

override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
    if (event != null) {
        if (event.sensor.type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sensor_value_accelx).text =
                event.values[0].toString()
        }
    }
}


override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_LOW)
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mAccelerometer)
}
```

Any help in where to look for the problem or any ideas on how to solve the issue would be very helpful.

I did some digging and found that there is a thing called Logcat.
Here is the error that it reports:

> > 2020-10-02 14:35:28.604 11040-11040/com.example.sensors E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> > Process: com.example.sensors, PID: 11040
> > kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: Not yet implemented
> > at com.example.sensors.MainActivity.onAccuracyChanged(MainActivity.kt:63)
> > at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:835)
> > at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
> > at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
> > at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
> > at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> > at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> > at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> > at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

This post fixed my issue.
[kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: not implemented Error from ImageButton Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503780/kotlin-notimplementederror-an-operation-is-not-implemented-not-implemented-err)

The Logcat log was very helpful in identifying the problem.  Although I do think this is a really bad way to handle a TODO statement.